# Python OpenCV: Finding tangent of a curvature and detecting intersections with another circle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry

I am doing a line detecting software. I can successfully detect the contour of line as array of points.
Now I am trying to extract information from it such as approx angle and error from center (see images below).

input image:

[image: input image]

output image:

[image: output image]

---

**Output image description:**
*Yellow circle* is area of interest, but centered on intersecting point of red x-axis line and detected line. Center of this circle is marked with big blue point.

*Green line* is the actual output. After cropped image with yellow circle, I am going to use OpenCV's fitLine function. This will give me my precious point locations, I guess.

**What I need:**

I want to use, as said above, fitLine method but since I cannot locate the intersecting point -between mid-x-axis and detected white line- I cannot crop image and so on. So, I need to locate the point (shown in big blue point in output image).

Answer (score 0):

**I answer my own question on behalf of the power of research:**

I realized that circular mask is not needed since I am cropping the image to find average curve, but still managed to crop a circular area just to be sure I can.

After cropping image to work with area of interest, I simply used fitLine method with DIST_L2 distance. That was all I wanted. 
Note that Python's builtin function `sorted` was not able to sort my contours by area.